# Bug from nested subscriptions in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying nest subscriptions within "subscribe" as some data depends on the response of the previous subscription. (Data flows down the subscription chain till it is stored in an array)

I have an array of IDs, I call a service to convert those IDs to Objects.
Code looks like this:

```
idArray.forEach(id =>
     this.getObjByID(id)));
}

getOjByID(ID: number): void {
  this._APIService.getObjByID(ID).subscribe(
    obj => {
        this.getDefaultConfig(obj);
    });
}
```

These Objects are then passed to get a config file for the Obj.
Code looks like this:

```
  getDefaultConfig(obj: any): void {
      this._APIService.getDefaultConfig(obj.id).subscribe(
          res => {
              obj.config = res;
              this.getPrices(obj);
          });
  }
```

Lastly, this object is passed its config to a final subscription, where a price object is appended to the object, and the object is then pushed to an array of objects (and is then rendered on the screen.) Code looks like this:

```
  getPrices(obj: any): void {
      this._PriceService.getPrice(obj).subscribe(
          res => {
              obj.price = res;
              this.objs.push(obj);
          });
  }
```

I don't understand subscribe/observables enough to understand the cause of this bug that I am experiencing. Essentially, I am using subscribe to extract the value of the response. The expected behavior is for this chain to be run as many times as the number of ids I have in my idArray, however, it appears that some subscriptions (or functions) are being run again. I have no errors in the console, my only indicator is the number of items int he final array "objs".

I have tried adding ".first()" or ".take(1)" before ".subscribe" on all my functions and this appears to have fixed duplicate obj objects in my objs array, however they all had the same "price" object.

What am I doing wrong with observables that is causing this to happen?

Comment: Do you have duplicate ids in your `idArray`?

Comment: No I do not. The ids come from a distinct function in mongodb. Notice that when I used ".take(1)" before every subscription, the objs array had unique objects (however their price object was identical..) @Zircon

Comment: Ok...next, does your APIService do any caching? Can you get the same DefaultConfig object for different IDs from `getDefaultConfig`? Essentially, I am driving at strange behavior I know of from `subscribe` which is caused by multiple subscriptions to the same observable. Do you think this would apply to your case?

Comment: You could also just try and add ".share" wherever you're creating the observable (the APIService). If it works I can offer an explanation.

Comment: I have implemented 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-http-cache' but I doubt this is causing it; you can't get the same defaultConfig for different ids - I don't know if the config is also the same when I use take(1); I think multiple subscriptions to the same observable might be  causing it. If there is a proper way to nest these API calls, I'll do it. Tell me more about share - maybe post an answer? I  don't know what it is or how to add it. @Zircon

Comment: @Zircon, I added .share() to ALL my this.http.get requests in my services, and now price object is null, it used to have values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be caused by a strangely-expected behavior of subscribing to the same `Observable` more than once. I ran into this issue when i was caching API responses through my service.

The idea is that when you subscribe to an observable a second time, the value is retrieved again (It's a "hot" observable), so the first subscription also receives the new (or same) value, thus your next layer of functions are being called twice (or more depending on how many subscribers there are).

You can easily fix this by adding `.share()` to the end of your observable wherever it's being created. For example, here's a snippet of a code in my current project:

```
const resp = this.http.get(url)
  .map( /* Some stuff is done and a value is returned */ )
  .catch(this.handleError)
  .share();

return resp;
```

A good explanation that really helped it click for me is here:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html

You've mentioned that this change caused your end objects to be null. I'm not sure if that's caused by some issue in the code. I'll keep this solution posted because it is what worked for me in your case.

(I was doing the same thing - exactly three levels of subscriptions - but the results were fine after adding `.share` in my case.)

Comment: this answer was not helpful, but you did mention something about caching, I removed the caching module, and viola it worked! Thanks for that!